# Flutter access ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments before Widget Build

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety, flutter-routes

I have arguments that are being passed through a namedRoute. I access them currently with:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as UserPack;
```

In my widget Build. I am trying to create a function for a stream that needs data from `args` but unfortunately the I cant access args outside of the Widget Build Which means I can not get the `packID` for the `streamIndividualPackList()`. I need to build that Stream before the Widget Build.

```
class IndividualPack extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndividualPack({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<IndividualPack> createState() => _IndividualPackState();
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamIndividualPackList(
    String packID) {
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  return db
      .collection('PackList')
      .doc(packID)
      .collection('PackContents')
      .orderBy('itemName')
      .snapshots();
}

class _IndividualPackState extends State<IndividualPack> {
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  //gets the Firebase db
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final PageController pageViewController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as UserPack;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModalRoute` depends on context, you can use nullable data with `addPostFrameCallback` to assign it.

```dart
  int? data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      data = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as int?;
    });
  }
```

You just nullable data inside build method.

```dart
  int? data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  data ??= ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as int?;
```

Do a null check before using nullable data.

Comment: So code checks out no errors. But after doing a test, its not actually retrieving the args. 

I tried to print 'packID' and it comes up emtpy:

https://pastebin.com/5a9DGiCY

Comment: try to check the place from of sending data/navigation, just to be it is actually getting packID or not on top level.

Comment: It is, I just checked.

Comment: So it looks like I needed to wrap the variabels in set state in the init when I set them! When I do that the app works.... But I get this error in the debug console:

The following assertion was thrown building IndividualPackListItems(dirty):
a document path must be a non-empty string
'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart':
package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty'